# The formula of $(a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'm trying to calculate $S^2$ with $S = 111\cdots1$ ($n$ number of $1$s) so I'm thinking of rewriting that to $(1
\cdot10^n + 1\cdot10^{n-1} + \cdots)^2$

That's why I want to get the above formula.

Comment: Not sure what you expect here.  Have you tried working this out for various values of $n$?  For $n=15$, the result is $12345679012345654320987654321$ for instance.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you wrote your starting number as $\frac {10^n-1}9$.  At least that gives you some expression for the square...is that enough?

Comment: $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2+2\sum_{i=2,j<i}^n a_ia_j$

Comment: Note, the expression $1\cdot10^n+1\cdot10^{n-1}+\cdots$ is $111\ldots1$ with $n+1$, not $n$, $1$s, as $1\cdot10^1+1\cdot10^0=11$ shows.

Comment: Minor typo : if there are $n$ number $1$'s, then the leftmost digit is $1 \times (10)^{(n-1)}$.  Beyond that, assuming that you are in fact interested in $(10)^n + 10^{(n-1)} + \cdots + 1$, the **shortcut** is that $\displaystyle S = \frac{10^{(n+1)} - 1}{9}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $111...1$ (n times 1)

$$111...1=10^0+10^1+10^2+...+10^{n-1}=\frac{1-10^n}{1-10}=\frac{10^n-1}{9}$$

$$(10^0+10^1+10^2+...+10^{n-1})^2=(\frac{10^n-1}{9})^2=\frac{10^{2n}-2\times 10^n+1}{81}$$

Comment: additional question: Is there a rule of digits of (11...1)^2?